# Oppo Find X6 Pro is detected as OPPO Reno 10 Pro 5G, how to reset the firmware?

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, device-firmware, stock-rom, oppo

I have just bought a second-hand Oppo Find X6 Pro and it has a global ROM on it. I don't know how they did it because there's no global version of the phone, but I think they might have tweaked the firmware because everything seems valid, except it hasn't got any updates and its security patch is of June which is pretty behind for this device. This is the version on it: PGEM10_13.1.1.144(EX01). The (EX01) OPPO Reno 10 Pro 5G has it and it stands for a European version, I think. That's why I say they might have tweaked something because even Google recognizes the device as OPPO Reno 10 Pro 5G.

[image]

> **Check your Oppo Reno10 Pro 5G**
>
> Google sent a notification to your Oppo Reno10 Pro 5G. Tap **Yes** on the notification, then tap **17** on your phone to verify that it's you.

So I wanted to roll back to stock firmware. I downloaded different stock ROMs, but there wasn't any way to flash them on the device. Can someone help me and go back to the stock ROM?

- I tried https://oppostockrom.com/oppo-find-x6-pro-pgem10 but didn't figure it out.
- I also used the QPST Flash Tool, but the firmware didn't contain anything to open it inside QPST like `.hex` or `.mbn`. It just had `.elf` for the programmer which when I chose it to flash the ROM, it said error FireHose.
- The recovery mode also doesn't have a local update and online update.
- When I reboot to EDL using adb, it just shows a black screen, but the computer does recognize Qualcomm 9008. I think the recovery is also not stock.

I will attach the system information:

[image]
[image]

Comment: No bro that's not the case not the mediatek neither the fake phone because I check IMEI it's a valid oppo find x6 pro and and it's not media Tek because only find x6 is mediatek the x6 pro is 8 gen 2